# MVC default Route Denied Access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have an MVC application -->MyApp, I have a controller --> mycont.
When I enter my site as [www.mysite.com/MyApp/Mycont/index](http://www.mysite.com/MyApp/Mycont/index), it goes to the index page as expected.
When I type my site as [www.mysite.com/MyApp/Mycont](http://www.mysite.com/MyApp/Mycont), I get a `403 access denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.` message.
Here is my route config:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");           
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Mycont",
        url: "Mycont/",  // also tried "Mycont"  "Mycont/{action}"
              defaults: new { controller = "Mycont", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
 }
```

The controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Myrole")]    
public class MycontController : Controller
{  
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    { .... }
}
```

After performing an error trace I see that IIS cycles looking for the following pages:  /MyApp/Mycont/default.htm   .../default.aspx  ../index.htm but does not look for .../index.cshtml It apparently tries to open the directory ../MyApp/Mycont/.  Why is IIS ignoring the MVC controller action?

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you samwu.  I edited my question after looking at the failed request tracing log

Comment: What you need to post is the content of the failed request tracking log. It is impossible to analyze your problem just through these descriptions.